# Capture Spring MVC DispatcherServlet exceptions with ExceptionResolver

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception

I am trying to return a valid JSON body for every request of an Spring MVC service, both correct and invalid.

Using `@ExceptionHandler` and a combination of `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`, `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` and my own `AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver` I am able to process and set a body for almost all invalid requests that are dispatched to a valid controller or rejected by Spring Security.

However, errors thrown by the `DispatcherServlet` like `noHandlerFound`, can't be intercepted, so the response has a valid HTTP status code like 404, but the body contains the Tomcat default XML error.

Anybody knows how to set up or configure an Spring Exception Resolver so all failed requests are intercepted and a valid JSON body could be set?

Answer (score 0):

[There is a section explaining](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) how is spring handling exception resolver for dispatcher servlet:

> The dispatcher's exception resolution strategy can be specified via a
>   HandlerExceptionResolver, for example mapping certain exceptions to
>   error pages. Default are AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver,
>   ResponseStatusExceptionResolver, and DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.
>   These HandlerExceptionResolvers can be overridden through the
>   application context. HandlerExceptionResolver can be given any bean
>   name (they are tested by type).

to be able to support Dispatcher exception handling overriding you have to implement `HandlerExceptionResolver` and `Ordered`  class and declare the implementation as spring bean. You must return `getOrder` value as `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to override any other existing handler.